# Migration error with SmallDateTime datatype

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I am using the following C# code in my Entity class:

```
[Column( TypeName = "SmallDateTime")]  
public string LoginTime { get; set; }
```

But I get an error during code-first migration:

`Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(161,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.String[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=Max,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]' of member 'LoginTime' in type 'standardvba.DAL.HitMaster' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.smalldatetime[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=0]' of member 'LoginTime' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.HitMaster'.`

I am using **SQL Server 2012** as my database

Comment: Since when is a `string` a `DateTime`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We have to specify the datatype explicitely as

```
public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: This disrespects SO rules. You should have accepted my answer instead of re-writing it 3 years later and accept yours which is just rephrasing of mine :)

Answer (score 4):

You are mapping .Net datatype `string` to SQL datatype `SmallDateTime`

Change the data type of `LoginTime` to `DateTime`